# How can I write Annotation member with using JavaPoet?

Tags: java, code-generation, scaffolding, javapoet

I want to generate an annotation with its members. The structure of annotation is

`public className (@Value("${topics.className.command}") String className){ }`
Because of $ sign I take error. Pls help me how can I write this structure?
The places I wrote as className are variable. This will take from users.

```
`ParameterSpec parameterOfConst = ParameterSpec.builder(String.class, className )
                .addAnnotation(
                        AnnotationSpec.builder(value)
                                .addMember("{$topics." +"", "$S", className.toLowerCase() + ".command}")
                                .build())`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ParameterSpec parameterOfConst = ParameterSpec.builder(String.class, className)
        .addAnnotation(
                AnnotationSpec.builder(value)
                        .addMember("value", "\"$${topics." + className.toLowerCase() + ".command}\"")
                        .build())
        .build();
```

That is the answer of my question